# Get System32 directory in kernel

Tags: c, windows, kernel

Can anybody give me a code which would return full path to System32 directory for Windows kernel driver?

Comment: Most systems don't have a System32 directory.   Those who would like to help answer your question will probably find it helpful if you give more specific information in your question.

Comment: i ask for Windows. As i know all windows OS have System32, at least Vista/7/8

Comment: system("set windir") + "\system32"

Comment: @BlackBear: I think the author meant the windows kernel support routine that returns the full path (i.e. fills the `UNICODE_STRING` object).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724373(v=vs.85).aspx sorry if I'm being rude but I'm quite ill.. :(

Comment: @BlackBear: it's ok, I'm ill too :)  Your suggestion don't help: `GetSystemDirectory` is a Win32 API routine, provided to the code running in the **user mode**. It's inaccessible to the drivers

Comment: @valdo: then someone other will answer, I don't know anything more about this ;)

Comment: Since the system32 directory never moves, one alternative approach would be to save the path somewhere during installation of the device driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're lucky one. [There's an open-source example that demonstrates exactly what you're looking for](http://www.driverentry.com/resources/systemrootpath.htm).

AFAIK there's no equivalent to a function such as `GetSystemDirectory` or whatever. However you may access the system-reserved file system objects by using symbolic links.

directory using a symbolic link.

The reserved symbolic link for the "system32" directory is `L"\\SystemRoot"`

Comment: Biggest limitation are the IRQLs, but the sample is quite well documented. +1